# Extra backslash in URLs

Tags: foursquare

Has anyone noticed that the service started sending the image's URL with an extra backslash before every slash?

e.g.:
"icon": "https:\ /\ /foursquare.com\ /img\ /categories\ /food\ /default.png".

instead of:
https://foursquare.com/img/categories/food/default.png

Is this normal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a extra backslash. Am I just blind? Its probably just a programmer's typo though...

Comment: sorry bro, i had to add a "space" after each backslash for it to appear correctly here.

Comment: as i developed my own json parser, maybe i have to skip the backslash while reading it... is this it?

Comment: Yeah, to me it just looks like a bug in the programmers code. Perhaps he was trying to escape forward slashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We (foursquare) made the change yesterday to the way we serialize JSON output, but should have done so in a way that won't break any modestly mature JSON handler. We may tweak how we do serialization in the future (always in compliance with the JSON spec) and we recommend you build your system to be robust against future changes.